# GMock C Framework Functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

At the moment I am a little bit stucked with the following problem, as I currently do not know on which way to solve it. The aim is to mock some c functions which come along with **fcntl.h**, like open a file. As a result, I build up a GMock structure that looks like this:

Mock Class:

```
class FileHandlingLib_MOCK
{
public:
    virtual ~FileHandlingLib_MOCK() {}

    //mock
    MOCK_METHOD2(open, int(const char* t1, int i1));
};
```

A Fixture:

```
class TestFixture : public ::testing::Test
{
    ...
}
```

Mocked open function:

```
int open(const char* t1, int i1)
{
    return TestFixture::_fileHandlingMock->open(t1, i1);
}
```

If I do something like this, it works flawless:

```
TEST_F(FileHandlingUnitTesting, openMatch)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*_fileHandlingMock, open("path_to_file", ::testing::Matcher<int>(1))).WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return(int(12)));

    int a = open("path_to_file", 1);
}
```

However, if the open function is nested into another function (where the fcntl.h is included, the code itself), the mock will never be called. Does that mean that the expected call "scope" is limited to the TEST_F itself?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. It seems that your problem is about double definition of `open()` function. I suppose you don't `#include <fcntl.h>` in your test function, otherwise it shouldn't compile. What happens here is: when you call your function manually in test, your own implementation is called. But your production code has no idea about existance of your own implementation and always uses `<fcntl.h>` for it's purposes.  
What you should do: change your production code to inject mock into it (wrapper design pattern may come in useful).

Comment: You can wrap all calls to functions from `fctnl.h`in an abstract class, and make two children of it: implementation, which calls real `fcntl.h` functions, and mock, which is just a GMock class.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks for your input. Indeed your second answer matches the solution for my problem, that's what I was also thinking about.